# Как сделать видео-конференцию на Django

Tags: python, django

Нужно реализовать на сайте что-то на подобии видео-конференции, как это можно сделать на Django ? P.S Я знаю о EasyRTC но мне нужно на django так как писать два отдельных сервиса ...

Comment: В случае применения WebRTC, где клиенты сами соединяются друг с другом, для серверной части отличий от обычного сайта практически нет. Сервер нужен только для того, чтобы один клиент мог передать другому свой адрес и порт. А вот если видео-поток нужно передавать через сервер, то Django для этого не подойдёт, нужно что-то асинхронное.

Comment: Для видеопотока можно попробовать django channels